# Is $H(k || m) \oplus k$ secure?

Tags: hash, mac, hash-signature

It is known that $H(k || m)$ (when using SHA1) is an insecure MAC function since it is vulnerable to hash length extension.

But what about $H(k || m) \oplus k$? A normal hash length extension seems to be impossible now. Even if the same key is used several times, I see no problem as long as the output of $H$ is random enough. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE Is this homework question? What is the origin of this question?

Comment: Note that for the security properties of SHA-3, just $H(k \| m)$ is considered secure - KMAC isn't much else than that (but it uses SHAKE, not SHA).

Comment: @kelalaka I was going through some CTF writeups and found the hash length extension attack. Now I'm just wondering about this construction.

Comment: It is overkill for secure hash functions like SHA3 and Blake2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $H$ defined as: SHA-512, with it's output XORed with the first 512 bits of the input message (padded with zeroes for short message). With such $H$, the proposed MAC is insecure. Yet, as far as we know, this $H$ is no worse than SHA-512 from a standard standpoint.

Argument: observe that if $H(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)=\operatorname{SHA-512}(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)\oplus m_1$ and $\operatorname{MAC}_k(m)=H(k\mathbin\|m)\oplus k$, then for 512-bit key¹ $k$ it holds $\operatorname{MAC}_k(m)=\operatorname{SHA-512}(k\mathbin\|m)$. Therefore this $\operatorname{MAC}$ is susceptible to the length extension attack².

Therefore, it is impossible to prove that $H(k\mathbin\|m)\oplus k$ is a secure MAC without some insight into the internal structure of $H$.

I'm rather confident the proposed MAC construction is practically secure for hashes of the SHA-2 family, and even for SHA-1. We might want to *prove* security under the assumption the hash has [Merkle-Damgård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) structure, a compression function built from a block cipher $E$ per the [Davies-Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer) construction, with appropriate block and key size for $E$. I think this would be possible under the ideal cipher model, but not a standard model of security of $E$. The problem is that XORing the key with the output of a block cipher can weaken it. That's the case e.g. for AES-128 in decryption mode, where the XOR removes a round's worth of security.

---

¹ For key of arbitrary size, $\operatorname{MAC}_k(m)=\operatorname{SHA-512}(k\mathbin\|m)\oplus F_{|k|}(m)$ where $F_{|k|}(m)$ is $0^{\min(|k|,512)}$, followed by the first $\min(\max(512-|k|,0),|m|)$ bits of $m$, followed by $0^{\max(512-|k|-|m|,0)}$. This still allows attack.

² Contrary to what I wrote initialy, we can't recover $k$ from queries.

Comment: I'm having a hard time proving that $H$ is a collision resistant hash function. Let $H(m_1\|m_2) = \mathrm{SHA}(m_1\|m_2)\oplus m_1$. Given a collision of $H(m_1\|m_2)$ we need to give a collision for $\mathrm{SHA}$. Let $m_a, m_b$ be two colliding inputs of $H$ with $m_a \neq m_b$ and $H(m_a) = H(m_b)\iff\mathrm{SHA}(m_{a_1}\|m_{a_2})\oplus m_{a_1} = \mathrm{SHA}(m_{b_1}\|m_{b_2})\oplus m_{b_1}$. It's easy to derive a collision if $m_{a_1} = m_{b_1}$, but what if they are distinct? Can we bound the probability that they are distinct?

Comment: @cisnjxqu: I think we could prove that $H$ defined such that $H(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)=\mathrm{SHA}(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)\oplus m_1$ is collision resistant under a model of $\mathrm{SHA}$ as a random oracle. However that's a poor model, since it does not account for the length-extension property. I think we could more laboriously prove that with a finer model of $\mathrm{SHA}$ where we use the actual Merkle-Damgård construction, and a round function modeled by a random oracle.

Comment: That might be possible, yes. I suppose my question is whether there is a collision resistant hash function (here $\mathrm{SHA}$) such that $H$ is _not_ collision resistant.

Comment: @cisnjxqu : Yes. Example: define $S(m)$ to be the first bit of $m$, concatenated with an ideal hash of the rest of $m$. $S$ is collision-resistant, yet $H$ defined by $H(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)=S(m_1\mathbin\|m_2)\oplus m_1$ is not, since the first bit of the input of $H$ has no influence on the outcome.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks a lot! Can you give me some more tips on how to recover the key using hash length extension? I can't figure it out..

Comment: @Johny Dow : I was wrong, we can't recover the key. See modified first two paragraphs of the answer.